# Plotly color palette

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating Tree map in R. I work with Plotly library. Plotly has a specific palette of colors that you can see below. Below you can see my data and my code

```
    df1<-structure(list(manuf = c("AMC", "Cadillac", "Camaro", "Chrysler", 
                                  "Datsun", "Dodge", "Duster", "Ferrari", "Fiat", "Ford", "Honda", 
                                  "Hornet", "Lincoln", "Lotus", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Merc", "Pontiac", 
                                  "Porsche", "Toyota", "Valiant", "Volvo"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                      2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                       "data.frame"))

treemap<-plot_ly(data = df1,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~count,
                 labels= ~manuf,
                 parents=  ~test,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")  %>%
  layout(title="", 
         annotations =
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1,
                title = "", 
                text = " ",
                showarrow = F,
                xref='paper',
                yref='paper'))

treemap
```

This code produces Treemap as the map shown below. In this plot, Merc has the largest share of 22 % and is the blue color.

[image]

So far, so good. But problem arise when I change some values in the data, as shown in the data below. Now instead of Merc in the first place is AMC with 44.6 %. Below you can see the data and code

```
df2<-structure(list(manuf = c("AMC", "Cadillac", "Camaro", "Chrysler", 
                              "Datsun", "Dodge", "Duster", "Ferrari", "Fiat", "Ford", "Honda", 
                              "Hornet", "Lincoln", "Lotus", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Merc", "Pontiac", 
                              "Porsche", "Toyota", "Valiant", "Volvo"), count = c(25L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))

df2$test<-1

treemap<-plot_ly(data = df2,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~count,
                 labels= ~manuf,
                 parents=  ~test,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 #marker = list(colors = ~colr),
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")  %>%
  layout(title="", font = t,
         annotations =
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1,
                title = "", 
                text = " ",
                showarrow = F,
                xref='paper',
                yref='paper'))

treemap
```

This code produces Treemap as shown below.

[image]

Now in this Treemap, colors are different compared to the first Treemap. Namely Merc in the first plot is blue in color while in the second plot is orange.

So can anybody help me how to produce Treemap with the **same colors for the same names**. I prefer to have this **colors** as is shown in these Treemaps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tree map and labels in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707357/tree-map-and-labels-in-plotly)

Comment: tried running it and got "object 'test' not found", could you clarrify?